# Integrate ADFS with Angular

Tags: angular, apache, httpd.conf, adfs, mellon

I have an angular application whose login page is available at: hostname/login. This login used a user table on my db.
Now for needs I had to integrate the login with an ADFS server. I used the mod_auth_mellon in Apache.
However, I need to pass two info that mellon provides to the angular application.
I would like to use these two pieces of information, ie the user and the group, to login to my angular application.
How can I solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you use a deprecated Apache module?

Comment: what do you recommend to use?

Comment: Nothing particular, was just wondering why a deprecated module for a brand new authentication

Comment: It is the only solution I have found for now.
They only provided me with the FederationMetadata.xml, and from that I configured everything.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, you ever figure anything out?